# Avoid img cropping in responsive section (background-image loaded in the CSS)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make a div that contains an image responsive.

I have tried two options:

a) The problem with the first one is that the image gets cropped (width) when the window size gets small.

b) The problem with the second one is that there is a big space vertically when the window --> image width gets smaller.

I am thinking of staying in the first solution and either use the `@media` tag and try changing some things there. Unless, there is an obvious way to easily change the current css. Alternatively, I can use the second solution and try changing the parent `div` settings.

Snipplet below:

```css
blockquote {
 padding: 700px 0 0 0;
 margin: 10px 0 25px 0;
}

.section {
  background:#ccc;
 position: relative;
 padding: 94px 0 67px 0;
 display: block;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}

#quotes-wrapper {
 height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 background: url(http://www.apolosiskos.co.uk/references.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
 -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
 -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
 -o-background-size: 100% auto;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 display: block;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 position: relative
}

 

#quotes-wrapper2 {
    background: url(http://www.apolosiskos.co.uk/references.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="section no-padding" id="section4">
  <div id="ancor4"></div>
  <div id="quotes-wrapper">
   
        <blockquote>
          <p>&quot;Skillmap&quot;</p>
        </blockquote>
  
    <div class="overlay2"></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="section no-padding">
  <div id="quotes-wrapper2">
   
        <blockquote>
          <p>&quot;Skillmap&quot;</p>
        </blockquote>
  
    <div class="overlay2"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem right, I would recommend to scale the div with background by proportion:

```css
.quotes-wrapper {
  background-image: url(http://www.apolosiskos.co.uk/references.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 66.6%;
}
```

```html
<div class="quotes-wrapper">
  <blockquote>
    <p>&quot;Skillmap&quot;</p>
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

It will not crop, and it will not create empty space without background. The important part is a `padding-top` in `quotes-wrapper`. Its value should be set as a ratio of height to width. It works because the padding size is relative to width.

Comment: I ll give it a go.